# Is it possible to use DOTENV within SuiteScript environment inside Netsuite?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

Is it possible to use DOTENV within NetSuite? I am looking to protect password data in API calls. If not, what is the process you use to protect this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No you cannot use dotenv in suitescript.
2. Use [netsuite secrets management](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/article_160216486846.html).  That will let you store your secrets in netsuite in a secure fashion.